# about php 5.x create xml by dom document

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm using `DOMDocument` class of PHP to create a xml file, my code is:

```
    $xmlObject = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    //root node -- books
    $books = $xmlObject->createElement('books');
    //book node
    $book = $xmlObject->createElement('book');
    //book node's attribute -- index
    $index = new DOMAttr('index', '1');
    $book->appendChild($index);
    //name node
    $name = $xmlObject->createElement('name', 'Maozedong');
    //name node's attribute -- year
    $year = new DOMAttr('year', '1920');
    $name->appendChild($year);
    $book->appendChild($name);
    //story node
    $story = $xmlObject->createElement('story');
    $title = $xmlObject->createElement('title', 'Redrevolution');
    $quote = $xmlObject->createElement('quote', 'LeaveoffHunan');
    $story->appendChild($title);
    $story->appendChild($quote);
    $book->appendChild($story);
    $books->appendChild($book);
    if ($xmlObject->save('xml/books.xml') != false){
        echo 'success';
    }else{
        echo 'error';
    }
```

The content of books.xml is only one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

the other node is non-existent. Are there any errors in my code?

Comment: Im a fan of doing it all with strings. Make an XML string, save it to file. Your code will be much shorter, run faster and be readable. `$xmlString = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><books><book><index>1</index> .... etc"`  But asking if there are any errors with your code is asking for downvotes, even closure.

Answer (score -2):

I forget append the books node to $xmlObject.
add:
$xmlObject->appendChild($books);

Comment: Edit your original, instead of answer with a change